# Log4j suddenly stops logging

Tags: java, log4j, websphere

I'm build a Portlet application deployed to a WebSphere Portal Server running on Linux. Every Portlet WAR uses Log4j for logging with a configuration like this, having every WAR two Log files:

```
log4j.logger.im.the.package=DEBUG, InfoAppender, DebugAppender

log4j.appender.InfoAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.File=/tmp/infoWARName.log
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.DebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.File=/tmp/debugWARName.log
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

After deployment, everything works like charm and log files started filling. After some hours, and at the same time, the Logging stops and `info.log` and `debug.log` aren't updated at all. We need to redeploy the Portlet WAR in the server to get the logging starting again.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I'm starting to suspect it has to do with my Logging JARS. Currently, this are the JAR's inside my `WEB-INF/lib` folder:

```
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar
com.springsource.slf4j.api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
```

**Second Update:**

At hours from the bounty to end, this is how Log4j is configured in every Portlet Application. Here's `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:miAppLog4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And `miAppLog4j.properties` file is located in folder external to the WAR and to the Portal. We made it availbale in Portlet Classpath through a [Shared Library in WebSphere Portal](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/06062009015816pmwebp3y.htm).

Comment: Have you checked there is enough space for logs in `/tmp`?

Comment: I have checked and there's plenty space in the hard disk: Only 4% is used

Comment: Have you checked the SystemOut.log?

Comment: Nothing in SystemOut.log, in SystemErr.log there are some warnings of some missing appenders related to other Libraries (like Hibernate). Can that be the cause?

Comment: All portlets stop logging at the same time? Does that time correspond to when the rolling occurs?

Comment: The info/debug appenders for one WAR stop at the same time; but all the WAR's stop logging at a different time. How do I know what's my rolling time?

Comment: That appender rolls based on file size (I think default 10MB), so I'm just asking if the logging stops when the file gets large enough that log4j decides to roll over to the next file.

Comment: I see files of 203KB that suddenly stops logging, so I think its not related to size

Comment: If one of A's was good for you, could you accept it? Q is still open.

Comment: Problem was solved, but the answer is not below :S

Comment: In our case, we had hosting with a third company and they were adding a script that gzipped our logs (we didn't know) and the format they used to know if the log could be compressed was different to the format we used (we didn't know we couldn't change it) and so they were compressing them every day.

Answer (score 25):

You've provided some basic information, so I can only sketch some candidate causes and likelihood:

**1. Problem with file locks/handles/IO stream**

- Triggerred by log rolling?

  Negative in your case.  Your two separate log files (info and debug) stop at the same time for any given  WAR.
  Each file rolls at the default maximum size (10MB).  It's very unlikely that both logs would always roll at the same time.  The error must not be triggered by log rolling.  Extra confirmation by configuring `log4j.appender.InfoAppender.MaxFileSize=200MB`
- Triggerred by users manipulating Linux files?

  Negative in your case.  It's possible that user/sysadmin manipulating files could create locks or stale file handles.  Linux should never have problems with a user *tail*-ing a file (but windows does).  Linux can have problems with users zipping or editing files.  But your problem seems very repeatable, making this unlikely unless you have automated scripts manipulating log files.
- Triggerred by "competitive" config settings in Websphere or Spring, with duplicate use of same log files by server/framework?

  Seems unlikely in your case. Seems you haven't been setting Websphere commons logging configuration.  Commons logging is automatically included in the websphere server parent ClassLoader and can be configured to "wrap" to Log4J by configuring:

  File *commons-logging.properties*

  ```
  # Set application classloader mode as PARENT_LAST when deploying in WAS as .ear
  priority=1
  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
  ```
- Triggered by hardware problems/disk failure?

  **???**  Seems strange that such a problem would be very repeatable.

**2. Problem with java threads?**

- thread death or deadlock
- massive thread processing/contention in "other" code, so that code with logging is not run

  From your description, I assume that the application is still running and working fine with normal performance and functionality, but the logs are not written.  Can you confirm?  If so, then it's not a thread problem with the webapp threads.

  Also I can confirm that it isn't a thread problem within the Log4J logic, because the only time it creates/uses its own thread is when one of AsynchAppender/ExternallyRolledFileAppender/SocketAppender/TelnetAppender is used OR when PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch or DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch method is called.

  i.e. **Negative**.

**3. Changes to Log4J classes in ClassLoaders, with use of different configuration?**

- Parent ClassLoader clashes with Webapp ClassLoader

  E.g. Your webapps initially start with thier own configured classes from WEBINF directory and all is good, but later after some time a different app causes (or one of the portal server admin tools) causes a clashing class to be loaded into the parent ClassLoader and your app "picks up" this new illegal version of the class and fails.

  Quite possibly a problem - thousands of users on Google have struggled with Websphere class loaders.

Suggested Action:

- ensure all your web apps use PARENT_LAST ClassLoading - go to the Admin console and ensure that they have PARENT_LAST set within ALL WebApp configurations
- ensure you are getting Log4J internal error messages written to the console
  E.g. Deliberately test by forceably deleting the error log as admin while app is running, creating a stale handle.  If "Log4J:" error messages do not appear in console, then this is a serious problem.
  Next time the problem occurs, trap any such console messages and report them.  Also, you can set "-D log4j.debug" on JVM/websphere startup, to find out precisly what Log4J was doing before/during the problem - messages will go to console.
- do you really need to set the logging level to DEBUG for all of your packages & classes?  Better to set to INFO or WARN and only selectively set on when you are debugging specific problems?

That's alot of text..........  B^)

Comment: I added some extra details, maybe they could help

Answer (score 4):

For over 5 years, Log4j has hardly any bugs fixed: it's effectively a dead project.
If acceptable, **consider replacing it with Logback**, which implements SLF4j directly.

Logback and SLF4J are written by the same guy who wrote Log4J (Ceki), has an even more liberal license and has a good community. It is the successor to Log4J 1 in every way possible (except for its name).

Comment: Log4j is not dead:  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html

Comment: I meant Log4J 1 is dead. Log4J 2 (which didn't exist back then) is a different library that came later and - as far as I can tell - was written by a new team.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you have multiple WARs writing to the same log file. In our experience, log4j cannot do this reliably, particularly with the rolling appenders. When one goes to roll it, the others are confused and unable to log further. Or continue to log to the old file.

I suspect you're going to have to have each WAR log to a different file.

Comment: Every WAR has it's own Log4j configuration with its exclusive Log files. I made some edits to the original question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try moving the log file location somewhere other than the temporary file system.

Comment: I'll try that. Any reason to do that? Or any known issue?

Comment: I'm guessing that the OS may be trying to delete the file, which it should be free to do, since it's in /tmp. I've see Log4j stop writing entirely if the log file becomes unwritable for even a few seconds - it won't start writing again when it becomes writable.

Comment: Moved the log files to /home and the issue is still there. Although, the log4j config file is still in /tmp

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure why log4j is stopping in your application. But you could (should) upgrade to log4j 2.0. Switching shouldn't be much effort. You will need to rewrite your log4j.properties file to an XML file because the new version doesn't support properties file any longer.

In the Java Magazin an article stated that log4j 2.0 is behaving more robust in multithreaded environments, so there is a chance it will fix your issue. If it doesn't you still have the benefit of the new version.

It brings some nice features and enhancements (copied from the [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) site):

**API Separation**

The API for Log4j is separate from the implementation making it clear for application developers which classes and methods they can use while ensuring forward compatibility. This allows the Log4j team to improve the implementation safely and in a compatible manner.

**Improved Performance**

Log4j 2 performs faster than Log4j 1.x in critical areas and similarly to Logback under most circumstances. See Performance for more information. 
Support for multiple APIs
    While the Log4j 2 API will provide the best performance, Log4j 2 provides support for the SLF4J and Commons Logging APIs.

**Automatic Reloading of Configurations**

Like Logback, Log4j 2 can automatically reload its configuration upon modification. Unlike Logback, it will do so without losing log events while reconfiguration is taking place.

**Advanced Filtering**

Like Logback, Log4j 2 supports filtering based on context data, markers, regular expressions, and other components in the Log event. Filtering can be specified to apply to all events before being passed to Loggers or as they pass through Appenders. In addition, filters can also be associated with Loggers. Unlike Logback, you can use a common Filter class in any of these circumstances.

**Plugin Architecture**

Log4j uses the plugin pattern to configure components. As such, you do not need to write code to create and configure an Appender, Layout, Pattern Converter, and so on. Log4j automatically recognizes plugins and uses them when a configuration references them.

**Property Support**

You can reference properties in a configuration, Log4j will directly replace them, or Log4j will pass them to an underlying component that will dynamically resolve them. Properties come from values defined in the configuration file, system properties, environment variables, the ThreadContext Map, and data present in the event. Users can further customize the property providers by adding their own Lookup Plugin.