# Log4j logging stops intermittently

Tags: log4j, websphere, cluster-computing

We're experiencing some stoppages on our log4j(v1.2.8) INFO logs. We're using a WebSphere(8.5.5) clustered server(vertical) with 3 members that runs on a single machine(UNIX). Stoppage is random; no specific file size, time or when about to rollover

We've first suspected that is a volume related problem as we've tested before on a lower volumed server the problem doesn't occur. I've later tested overloading this server but I could not replicate the problem.

Average daily production is 175,000 INFO lines. A workaround is available by just changing the timestamp of the log files to resume logging.

Already looked into the suggested fix on [Log4j suddenly stops logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242035/log4j-suddenly-stops-logging) but nothing seemed to work. I'm hoping I could get some advise on were to look. Thank you.

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="TEST" />
    </root>

    <appender name="TEST" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="file" value="$test/directory/logs/test${com.test.log.server.name}.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="50" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] [%-12X{username}] [%-12X{servlet}] [%c{1}] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The value of ${com.test.log.server.name} is declared in WebSphere JVM custom properties on each application server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get any real answers, is there any reason *not* to at least try the latest log4j1.2.x, just in case something relevant was fixed? We've dropped in newer .x versions with zero impact.