# Log4j Shared Log file Rolling file appender issue

Tags: log4j, websphere-8

I was asked to assist in debugging a peculiar issue, related to log4J.
They are facing issues with the rolling file appender. There are multiple EJB applications writing to the same log file. Each application has its own log4j.properties.
Issue: The latest log files are being written to a file trace.log.x instead of trace.log.  Is there any setting which needs to be added? I could not really find an anomaly. Below are the settings.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A3
log4j.appender.A3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A3.File=$variable/trace.log
log4j.appender.A3.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.A3.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

I was wondering if I need to set the log4j at the server level instead of the app level. I don't like the idea though. I am not in favour of log file being shared. There is no log file corruption, but looks like the wrong file is getting updated

Comment: You have multiple properties files all pointing to the same log file? If so, I'm not surprised that is confusing log4j. Particularly if any rolling occurs (like where you have size-based rolling), that tends to confuse log4j when multiple copies of it are trying to reference the same file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14260293/796761

Comment: Yes, I suggested 2 things. I externalised the log4J.properties file. Added it to the jvm  property. then moved the logs to a separate file per ear. This seems to be working.